# passing external value to closure... error: capture of moved value

Tags: rust

I read a file given as an argument, but when I try to pass it to `handle_client` in a task at the bottom so that it can be written to the tcp stream when someone connects I get `error: capture of moved value: html`... what am I missing?

```rust
fn get_file_string(path_str: &String) -> String{
    let path = Path::new(path_str.as_bytes());
    let file = File::open(&path);
    let mut reader = BufferedReader::new(file);
    reader.read_to_string().unwrap()
}

fn main() {

    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:8001");
    let mut acceptor = listener.listen();

    let ref file_to_host = os::args()[1];
    let html = get_file_string(file_to_host).clone();

    fn handle_client(mut stream: TcpStream, html: String) {
        let write = stream.write_str(html.as_slice());
    }

    for stream in acceptor.incoming() {
        match stream {
            Err(e) => { println!("{}", e) }
            Ok(stream) => spawn(proc() {
                handle_client(stream,html)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: `.clone()` after `get_file_string` is useless, you only need to clone when you want a copy (to have **2** objects).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`html` is a `String`. Just like everything in Rust, a `String` is owned in exactly one place (if it satisfied `Copy`, it would be able to just duplicate it implicitly, but as it involves a heap allocation it’s definitely not). At present, you’re passing `html` to the `handle_client` function by value; therefore, when you call `handle_client(stream, html)`, both `stream` and `html` are moved into that function and are no longer accessible. In the case of `stream`, that doesn’t matter as it’s a variable from inside the loop, but `html` comes from outside the loop; if it let you do it, it would take it the first time and work fine, *but then it would be freed*; second time through the loop, you would have an invalid `String` being passed through.

The solution in this case, seeing as you’re passing it through `spawn` and so can’t pass a reference (the slice, `&str`) is to clone the value so that that value can be moved into the `proc` and into the `handle_client` call:

```
Ok(stream) => {
    let html = html.clone();
    spawn(proc() {
        handle_client(stream, html)
    })
}
```